# A Word for Voucher User

Tags: single-word-requests

Writing a financial software. looking for a word for the following situation

A voucher created for an expense, say transportation could be collected by either a branch or a team or an individual employee. Need a word to describe them. Thought of beneficiary, but since they're spending it for the company, it wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: I think the question should be rephrased. I am not able to understand it.

Comment: If they are **redeeming** the voucher then they could all be referred to as the **voucher_redeemer**

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Cybermonk, single word requests as yours are required to provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used. Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Comment: @MaxWilliams The voucher in this context is not a coupon.

Comment: In that case, you are going to need to describe the business process in more detail. How is the voucher used?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking correctly (!), *recipient* might be an appropriate choice.

Comment: voucher is an accounting book where you'd write down whom you're paying money and for what. If I am paying for transportation, the party that would use the given money could be a branch or an employee or a team. I've shortlisted recipient, party, and receiver

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Initially I went with Receiver. Later an accounting person asked me to rename it to 'Cost Center'.

Update: Renamed to cost center because the receiver though is correct in terms of English language, Cost Center is what is being used in the accounting world to describe Organization Units that incur expenses.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer you eventually went with. However, "cost center" doesn't really seem to fit to what you described, could you add some explanation as too *why* you were asked to rename it?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

*Vendor*

I think the *vendor* is the person or entity who provided a service or product, for which payment is required.

> A vendor is a person or business that supplies goods or services to a company. Another term for vendor is supplier. In many situations a company presents the vendor with a purchase order stating the goods or services needed, the price, delivery date, and other terms.

http://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-is-a-vendor

It sounds like you're using *voucher* to mean *invoice*.  Which is how *voucher* is used in Spanish (at least, in Mexico).

Comment: vendor would be correct if I'm referring to the travels agency in my transportation example above, but the word that I want is to refer to the people/group of people from my own organization who used the money to travel.

Comment: @Cybermonk - *payee*?